# Use TField.DisplayFormat to format a string not in dataset

Tags: delphi

A DataSet hooked to a grid has:

```
TField.DisplayFormat := '$######.00'
```

I want to build list of strings that are in a particular column of my grid with:

```
while NOT DataSet.EOF do
   StringList.Add(TField.DisplayText);
```

I had hoped for speed to do:

```
DataSet.DisableControls;
```

but this also disables the application of the DisplayFormat.

Not disabling the controls means this runs quite slowly (in the archaic, deprecated, "You should abandon it **now**"-Paradox/BDE.)

So, my question:

Is there a formatting function (say, DFFormat) that uses the same notation as TField.DisplayFormat?

Then I could do:

```
 DataSet.DisableControls;
 while NOT DataSet.EOF do
   StringList.Add(DFFormat(TField.Value));
```

Or, since there are only have a few data types, so I could do the code below and figure out ways to create a Format string that works:

```
 DataSet.DisableControls;
 while NOT DataSet.EOF do
   begin
     if TField.FieldType = ftString
        StringList.Add(AsString)     
     else if TField.FieldType = ftFloat then
        StringList.Add(Format(TField.Value, ...)
     else...
```

The code above wouldn't be much longer than shown, but I'm hoping there is a formatting function that uses TField's DisplayFormat.  Or am I asking too much?

Comment: DisplayText works OK even with DisableControls, in D2006 at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DisplayFormat` only applies to four `TField` descendants (`TAggregateField`, `TDateTimeField`, `TNumericField`, and `TSQLTimeStampField`). It seems to me this would be very easy to implement for three of them:

```
function TFieldToDisplayFormat(const Fld: TField): string;
begin
  Result := Fld.AsString;
  if (Fld is TDateTimeField) then
    Result := FormatDateTime(TDateTimeField(Fld).DisplayFormat,
      TDateTimeField(Fld).AsDateTime)
  else if (Fld is TNumericField) then
    Result := FormatFloat(TNumericField(Fld).DisplayFormat,
      TNumericField(Fld).AsFloat)
  else if (Fld is TSQLTimeStampField) then
    Result := SQLTimeStampToString(TSQLTimeStampField(Fld).DisplayFormat,
       TSQLTimeStampField(Fld).AsSQLTimeStamp);
end;

// Sample use
while not DataSet.Eof do
  SL.Add(TFieldToDisplayFormat(WhatEverField));
```

Comment: GREAT solution, as usual from you. Thanks, Ken.  Question: One place I need to use this is on calculated fields inside  DataSet.OnAcceptRecord.  Unfortunately, I've just found that OnCalculate hasn't yet been called at that point, nor can it be called. Any suggestions on how to use the above approach in that context?  Might I create a TField, populate it and then hand it to the above? What would I have to put in the TField to make your code work. (If this should be another question, let me know & I'll repost it...)

Comment: Hmmm... That I don't know. Creating a new TField wouldn't solve anything, as it would have the same content as the calculated field (uncalculated); if you could calculate it first, you could just directly call the formatting functions directly, passing the calculated value. I'm trying to see where you would need something formatted to `DisplayFormat` in the `OnAcceptRecord` event, though...

Comment: >>  I'm trying to see where you would need something formatted to DisplayFormat in the OnAcceptRecord event, though...   I need that to match a list of filter strings a user choose from a drop-down. If I'd "coded" it properly, my list of strings would have a TObject that contains the .Value, avoiding the problem. Your questioning this leads me to go back to the fix up the code. Thanks, again.  And, I wasn't thinking right, I can just hand a value that I calculate in code in the OnAccept routine to your code above.

Answer (score 3):

The format function which uses the TField depends of the type of the Field, in your case (for a descendent of [`TNumericField`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TNumericField)) you must use the [`FormatFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FormatFloat) passing as parameter the value of the field and the [`DisplayFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TNumericField.DisplayFormat) property.

```
FormatFloat(Field.DisplayFormat, Field.Value)
```